# GLSL - make effect only on one texture

Tags: java, glsl, libgdx, shader

I wish to blur my background, with the following fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform vec2 screenSize;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec4 v_time;

const float RADIUS = 0.75;

const float SOFTNESS = 0.6;

const float blurSize = 1.0/1000.0;

void main() {

    vec4 texColor = vec4(0.0); // texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord)
    texColor += texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord - 4.0*blurSize) * 0.05;
    texColor += texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord - 3.0*blurSize) * 0.09;
    texColor += texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord - 2.0*blurSize) * 0.12;
    texColor += texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord - blurSize) * 0.15;
    texColor += texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord) * 0.16;
    texColor += texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord + blurSize) * 0.15;
    texColor += texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord + 2.0*blurSize) * 0.12;
    texColor += texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord + 3.0*blurSize) * 0.09;
    texColor += texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord + 4.0*blurSize) * 0.05;

    vec4 timedColor = (vColor + v_time);

    vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / screenSize.xy) - vec2(0.5);
    float len = length(position);

    float vignette = smoothstep(RADIUS, RADIUS-SOFTNESS, len);

    texColor.rgb = mix(texColor.rgb, texColor.rgb * vignette, 0.5);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor.rgb * timedColor.rgb, texColor.a);
}
```

But the problem being is that the shader blurs all screen.. what should i write to make it focus on my background texture instead of all the screen?

Comment: I really do not understand what you mean by "it blurs all screen". That is usually the point of a convolution filter. You might be able to use the stencil buffer to mask parts of the screen off, but what would really help is if you showed a screenshot of what is happening and some explanation what you actually want (i.e. draw a circle around the part of the screen that is not the "background texture").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I gonna answer my question.

I wanted my shader program to blur only the background texture instead of all the screen.
so I created two shader programs, one for the background and one for the rest.
when the program draws the background it switches to the background shader, and after that is switches to the default shader.

Simple is that.

Comment: I didn't show a problem and asked for solution, I asked for way to implement my idea.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment shader applies to every pixel of triangle that you draw with that shader.
May be you apply shader to wrong triangles and problem is not shader.

That shader looks strange to me.

```
vTexCoord - blurSize
```

`vTexCoord` - is `vec2`

`blurSize` - is  `float`

The code will look more correct if you write something

```
vTexCoord - vec2(blurSize, 0.0)
```

Comment: It might look more correct, but that is not an equivalent expression. `vec2 - float` is actually equivalent to `vec2 - vec2 (float, float)`. Or in other words: `vTexCoord - blurSize` == `vTexCoord - vec2 (blurSize, blurSize)`. Scalars are promoted to vectors before the operation can be done, and then evaluated component-wise.